# Как передавать данные между потоками при помощи ExecutorService?

Tags: java, многопоточность, execute

Есть 2 потока:

```
final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
final Future<?> submit1 = service.submit(new Callable(...));
final Future<?> submit2 = service.submit(new Callable(...));
```

Когда в `submit1` происходит определенное событие, `submit2` должен об этом узнать, и остановиться. Как передавать флаги(или любые данные) между потоками, когда они уже запущены, если сигнал по которому эта остановка должна произойти, генерируется не в внутреннем классе, а в другом файле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать interrupt метод у потока, а в задаче проверять на isInterrupted() и, если он будет true, завершать работу.
Если же надо обмениваться данными межу потоками, то тут способов много:

- расшарить объекты, к которым будут иметь доступ потоки, не забыв, правда, эти операции синхронизировать;
- использовать блокируемые очереди;
- использовать барьеры или condition (если надо например дождаться данных от другого потока в текущем)

Расскажите чуть подробней, какой вид обмена вам нужен, можно будет дать более правильную рекомендацию.

Comment: У меня многопоточный поиск по содержимому текстовых файлов. Все файлы File лежат в ConcurrentLinkedQueue и есть ридер который их читает и ищет соответствие по заданной строке. И есть несколько таких потоков которые берут из этой очереди и сканируют файл. У каждого потока свой объект ридер. Мне надо чтобы когда один из потоков найдет искомое значение он сообщил второму что искать больше не надо.

Comment: В таком случае рекомендую сохранить все задачи в некоем списке, затем когда одна из задач найдет искомое вызвать для всех прочих таксков метод cancel(). А в самих задачах делать проверку на isInterrupted() который при значении true будет означать необходимость останова. Обычно эту проверку ставят в while

Comment: Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() делать. cancel(true) выставляет флаг в потоке исполняющем ваш код.

Comment: когда одна из задач найдет искомое вызвать для всех прочих таксков метод cancel()<<<А как мне вызвать у всех cancel()? В смысле как мне из того класса доступиться ко всем потокам? Если в каждом таске оставлять ссылку на список со всеми тасками то это двусторонняя зависимость получиться... Тоесть как мне узнав в одном из потоков что все я нашел добраться из него до объектов остальных потоков чтобы вызвать cancel?

Comment: Сделать список с вашими тасками в виде поля некоего класса, к которому они будут иметь доступ например. Если же вы используете шину сообщений, то можно оформить таск в виде отдельного класса, сделать событие отмены, подписаться на него, а потом вместо cancel() делать Thread.currentThread().interrupt()

Comment: Еще можно попробовать просто сделать пулу потоков shutdown(), но это крайность и часто не удобно.